# how to delete every row not containing a list of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to delete any remaining row in a table that doesn't exist in a list a program I'm making generates. This is one of the ways I have tried. Each way I change this I continue to get an 'invalid relational operator' error

```
delete from bb_pub.EPUB_AGENT_TRNPRT 
where '39800013','39800022','39800009','39800023','39800011','39900001','39800025','39800016','39800014','39600003' 
not in (TRANSPORT_ID);
```

Comment: Did you mean `WHERE transport.id NOT IN (...)`?

Comment: the column is called "transport_id" and while it's values are numerical the data type for that column is VARCHAR2(40 CHAR)

Comment: Works in an `in` clause Yoda notation does not

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  delete from bb_pub.EPUB_AGENT_TRNPRT 
    where TRANSPORT_ID 
    not in
    ('39800013','39800022','39800009','39800023',
    '39800011','39900001','39800025','39800016','39800014','39600003');
```

Comment: AH! There it is, thank you! This entire project has been a learning experience.